# Triangle solution by Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

```
da = 1.12; db = 1.23; dc = 0.84;
NSolve[{2 a b/(a + b) Sin[(aA + aB)/2] == dc, 
  2 b c/(b + c) Cos[aA/2] == da, 2 c a (c + a) Cos[aB/2] == db, 
  Sin[aA]/Sin[aA + aB] == da/dc, Sin[aB]/Sin[aA + aB] == db/dc}, {a, 
  b, c, aA, aB}]
```

EDIT1:

We have 5 equations and 5 unknowns.

Angle bisector formula:

$$ dc=\frac{2ab}{a+b} \cos (C/2), \,  da=\frac{2bc }{b+c} \cos (A/2), \,  db=\frac{2ca }{c+a} \cos (B/2); $$

$$ A/2+B/2+C/2= \pi/2; $$

Law of Sines:

$$ \frac{\sin A}{\sin(A +B) }=\frac{da}{dc}, \quad  \frac{\sin B}{\sin(A +B)}= \frac{db}{dc} ;$$

Motivation was to be able to see a solution of a [question running on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1341896/construct-the-triangle-with-given-angle-bisectors) involving given bisectors of a triangle, I ran `Mathematica` problem using above known bisector lengths formula but am  encountering some error in the numerical itself..  it hangs. Please help with a clue what may be missing.

Comment: @Narasimhan In the third equation there is a syntax error 2c a; (semicolom ???). Can you reduce the equations, maybe some of them are combination of others...

Comment: the last two eqns are combination one of the other, so you have four eqns for five variables. I suggest to use `Reduce` to see where it goes...

Comment: "a running problem on MSE" - can you link to it, please?

Comment: Thanks @ José Antonio Díaz Navas , There are five unknowns and five equations I fixed that part, but the inverse functions and Reduce are often a hindrance. How is it Reduced? –

Comment: The problem ought to be much simpler if you specify a value for the inradius in advance, so that the coordinates are uniquely determined. You might also want to exploit the fact that the barycentric coordinates of the incenter are $\sin A:\sin B:\sin C$, where $A,B,C$ are the three internal angles.

Comment: you seem to have concocted a more complicated approach then the linked answer. Why?

Comment: OP has, as his problen reads given three concurrent lines that do not fix position of in-center ( with any definite ratio of intersections or lines marked on $l_1,l_2,l_3$. So I was attempting to find a general solution. The linked answer has conveniently  assumed the segmenting also as given, when in fact not given. When we refer to a line it is not just its  direction we are referring to..

Comment: By that token the sliding lines problem imho still remains unsolved... with lot of triangle combinations..

Comment: @george2079 Please visit the link, what I meant. The solution could be same, upto scale.

Comment: It may help if you used the same symbols or provided your own figure illustrating what your symbols mean.

Comment: Thanks, I am looking at circular arc loci for general problem

Comment: Unfortunately there is a missing `/` in the code. `2 c a (c + a)` should be `2 c a/(c + a)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**modified** (See @somos's comment, thanks)

I just detected the question some weeks to late.
But I can contribute a very simple straightforward solution using NMinimize:

```
da = 1.12; db = 1.23; dc = 0.84;
NMinimize[{1, 
2 a b/(a + b) Sin[(aA + aB)/2] == dc,
2 b c/(b + c) Cos[aA/2] == da, 
2 c a/(c + a) Cos[aB/2] == db, 
Sin[aA]/Sin[aA + aB] == da/dc, 
Sin[aB]/Sin[aA + aB] == db/dc}, {a,b, c, aA, aB}]

(*{1., {a -> 1.01212, b -> 0.807711, c ->3.43558, aA -> 1.0854,aB -> 1.33088}}*)
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is a missing `/` in the code. `2 c a (c + a)` should be `2 c a/(c + a)`.

Answer (score 2):

Solve the two last equations, which do not depend on a,b,c, separatly.

First TrigExpand (I rationalized the paramters)

```
list = {2 a b/(b + c) Sin[(aA + aB)/2] == dc, 
2 b c/(b + c) Cos[aA/2] == da, 2 c a/(c + a) Cos[aB/2] == db, 
Sin[aA]/Sin[aA + aB] == da/dc, Sin[aB]/Sin[aA + aB] == db/dc} // 
   TrigExpand;

abceq = list[[1 ;; 3]];

SinCoseq = list[[4 ;; 5]];

red = Reduce[SinCoseq, {aA, aB}];

sol = Solve[red]

(*     {{aB -> ConditionalExpression[-2 ArcTan[Sqrt[14345/23287]] + 
 2 \[Pi] C[1], (C[2] | C[1]) \[Element] Integers], 
  aA -> ConditionalExpression[-2 ArcTan[Sqrt[11023/30305]] + 
 2 \[Pi] C[2], (C[2] | C[1]) \[Element] Integers]}, {aB -> 
  ConditionalExpression[
2 ArcTan[Sqrt[14345/23287]] + 
 2 \[Pi] C[1], (C[2] | C[1]) \[Element] Integers], 
 aA -> ConditionalExpression[
 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[11023/30305]] + 
 2 \[Pi] C[2], (C[2] | C[1]) \[Element] Integers]}}     *)
```

C[1],C[2] can be oven or odd, that means there are two times four solutions for the abceq uations.

```
eq1 = abceq /. sol // 
   FullSimplify[# /. {C[1] -> 2 u, C[2] -> 2 v}, {u, v} \[Element] 
 Integers] &

eq2 = abceq /. sol // 
   FullSimplify[# /. {C[1] -> 2 u + 1, C[2] -> 2 v}, {u, v} \[Element] 
 Integers] &

eq3 = abceq /. sol // 
  FullSimplify[# /. {C[1] -> 2 u, C[2] -> 2 v + 1}, {u, v} \[Element] 
 Integers] &

eq4 = abceq /. sol // 
  FullSimplify[# /. {C[1] -> 2 u + 1, C[2] -> 2 v + 1}, {u, 
  v} \[Element] Integers] &

sol101 = NSolve[#, {a, b, c}] & /@ eq1

(*   {{{a -> 0.244769, b -> 0.230653, c -> -0.356331}}, {{a -> 1.31884, 
  b -> 0.99178, c -> 1.91994}}}     *)

sol102 = NSolve[#, {a, b, c}] & /@ eq2

(*  {{{a -> -1.31884, b -> 0.487807, c -> -1.91994}}, {{a -> -0.244769, 
   b -> -0.782936, c -> 0.356331}}}  *)

sol103 = NSolve[#, {a, b, c}] & /@ eq3

(*   {{{a -> 0.244769, b -> 0.782936, c -> -0.356331}}, {{a -> 1.31884, 
    b -> -0.487807, c -> 1.91994}}}    *)

sol104 = NSolve[#, {a, b, c}] & /@ eq4

(*    {{{a -> -1.31884, b -> -0.99178, c -> -1.91994}}, {{a -> -0.244769, 
    b -> -0.230653, c -> 0.356331}}}    *)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you make new variables and algebraic equations for the trigs then a solution can be obtained in reasonable time (this sort of thing has been done in a few prior MSE threads).

```
Clear[da, db, dc];
dvalRules = {da -> 1.12, db -> 1.23, dc -> 0.84};
trigRules = {Cos[a_] :> cs[a], Sin[a_] :> sn[a]};

eqns = {2 a b/(a + b) Sin[(aA + aB)/2] == dc, 
   2 b c/(b + c) Cos[aA/2] == da, 2 c a (c + a) Cos[aB/2] == db, 
   Sin[aA]/Sin[aA + aB] == da/dc, Sin[aB]/Sin[aA + aB] == db/dc};
polys0 = Numerator[
   Together[
    TrigExpand[
      Apply[Subtract, eqns, {1}] /. {aA -> 2*aA, aB -> 2*aB}] /. 
     trigRules]];
trigIdens = 
  Map[#^2 + Apply[sn, #]^2 - 1 &, Cases[Variables[polys0], cs[_]]];
polys = Join[polys0, trigIdens] /. dvalRules;
vars = Variables[polys];
```

Now sole the system.

```
AbsoluteTiming[solns = NSolve[polys, vars];]

(* During evaluation of In[103]:= Solve::ratnz: Solve was unable to solve the system with inexact coefficients. The answer was obtained by solving a corresponding exact system and numericizing the result.

Out[103]= {5.424746, Null} *)
```

Retain real-valued solutions.

```
realSolns = Select[solns, FreeQ[#, Complex] &];
{a, b, c} /. realSolns

(* Out[113]= {{-1.11217844394, 
  1.11217844394, -0.372460206543}, {1.40256957119, -1.40256957119, \
-0.932194784531}, {-1.25024995131, 
  0.314387064726, -0.314387064726}, {1.35457077085, 
  0.608749750689, -0.608749750689}, {-0.608749750689, -1.35457077085, 
  1.35457077085}, {-0.314387064726, 
  1.25024995131, -1.25024995131}, {-0.932194784531, 0.932194784531, 
  1.40256957119}, {-0.372460206543, 
  0.372460206543, -1.11217844394}, {-2.0632420756, -4.09496314451, 
  20.3694113194}, {-0.23991946789, 
  0.20831767403, -10.688097699}, {-2.82296467293, -0.534229776885, 
  2.91787741243}, {-0.563848363706, -2.20962845015, -0.928872449049}, \
{-0.785573051303, 2.74272228649, 
  12.2621124292}, {0.252745851079, -1.09244424909, -10.863435061}, \
{-0.314348110282, 1.04701586538, 1.74202830166}, {-0.230753295866, 
  0.474486543322, -1.72889992565}, {-0.252745851079, 1.09244424909, 
  10.863435061}, {0.785573051303, -2.74272228649, -12.2621124292}, \
{0.230753295866, -0.474486543322, 
  1.72889992565}, {0.314348110282, -1.04701586538, -1.74202830166}, \
{0.23991946789, -0.20831767403, 10.688097699}, {2.0632420756, 
  4.09496314451, -20.3694113194}, {0.563848363706, 2.20962845015, 
  0.928872449049}, {2.82296467293, 
  0.534229776885, -2.91787741243}, {0.372460206543, -0.372460206543, 
  1.11217844394}, {0.932194784531, -0.932194784531, -1.40256957119}, \
{-1.35457077085, -0.608749750689, 
  0.608749750689}, {1.25024995131, -0.314387064726, 
  0.314387064726}, {0.314387064726, -1.25024995131, 
  1.25024995131}, {0.608749750689, 
  1.35457077085, -1.35457077085}, {-1.40256957119, 1.40256957119, 
  0.932194784531}, {1.11217844394, -1.11217844394, 0.372460206543}} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It  appears exhaustive. (I  should learn more :) )  Can we further filter out triangles with one or two negative signs for $a,b,c,$ to plot the triangles around its in-center, and to capture any pattern? Also if it  is possible to get the old MSE post?

Comment: `In[970]:= 
posSolns = 
  Select[realSolns, Apply[And, Thread[({a, b, c} /. #) >= 0]] &];
{a, b, c} /. posSolns

Out[971]= {{0.563848363706, 2.20962845015, 0.928872449049}}`

Comment: Unfortunately there is a missing `/` in the code. `2 c a (c + a)` should be `2 c a/(c + a)`.

Comment: @Somos Seems to work with the corrected equation. It even gets faster and loses a warning message.

Answer (score 1):

```
{da, db, dc} = Rationalize[{1.12, 1.23, 0.84}];
N@Solve[{
    (2 a b Sin[(aA + aB)/2])/(a + b) == dc, 
    (2 b c Cos[aA/2])/(b + c) == da, 
    2 c a (c + a) Cos[aB/2] == db, 
    Sin[aA]/Sin[aA + aB] == da/dc, 
    Sin[aB]/Sin[aA + aB] == db/dc, 
    0 < aA < Pi, 0 < aB < Pi
    }, {aA, aB, a, b, c}, Reals, 
   Quartics -> False, Cubics -> False] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Output

> {2.08422,{{aA->1.0854,aB->1.33088,a->0.563848,b->2.20963,c->0.928872},
>   {aA->1.0854,aB->1.33088,a->2.82296,b->0.53423,c->-2.91788}}}

Comment: Unfortunately there is a missing `/` in the code. `2 c a (c + a)` should be `2 c a/(c + a)`.